# Expected Declaration Error in Swift When Accessing A Class Function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I am new to coding and am trying to grasp how classes work in Swift. I wrote the follow code in Xcode 7.2.1 and receive an error 'Expected declaration' which points at the first character in line 
`myFirstCar.refuel()`.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        class Car {

            var weight:Int = 1200
            var gas:Int = 100
            var maxGas:Int = 1000 

            func refuel() {
                if gas < 900 {
                    gas += 100
                } else {
                    gas += (maxGas - gas)
                }
         }
    }

    let myFirstCar = Car()

    myFirstCar.refuel()

}
```

I would like this code to run the `refuel()` function inside the class.

I have looked around and believe this is a problem with the initialization of the function inside the `Car` class.  I have tried initializing each variable in the class as well as initialize the function but I receive the same error code pointing at the same line.

I now think that I might be missing some vary fundamental rule when working with classes.

For instance, I do not know if the `class ViewController: UIViewController` is an issue because my `class Car` is contained within it and might be making the `Car` class a subclass of `ViewController`?

Like I said, I have looked around and found this code online which is essentially the same as mine.

```
class Tank {
    class var bonusDamage: Double {
        return Double(Upgrade.level) * 2.5
    }

    let baseDamage = 10.0
    var damage: Double {
        return self.baseDamage + Tank.bonusDamage
    }

    class func upgrade() {
        Upgrade.level += 1
    }

    struct Upgrade {
        static var level = 0
    }
}

var tank = Tank()

println(tank.damage)
// 10.0

Tank.upgrade()

println(tank.damage)
// 12.5

Tank.upgrade()

println(tank.damage)
// 15.0
```

If I copy and paste the code into Xcode, it gives the same error 'Expected declaration' at the line:

```
println(tank.damage)
// 10.0
```

I guess my real problem is I do not understand this error.  If someone could point me in a direction to look for an answer, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that the Car class should not be nested inside the ViewController class. Ideally, move it out to its own file `Car.swift`. You also seem to be using an old version of Swift, since `println` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because you are calling a function in the wrong place:

```
myFirstCar.refuel()
```

Likewise for:

```
println(tank.damage)
// 10.0

Tank.upgrade()

println(tank.damage)
// 12.5

Tank.upgrade()

println(tank.damage)
// 15.0
```

One has to call this within in `func` scope; for instance:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    myFirstCar.refuel()

    /* 

    println(tank.damage)
    // 10.0

    Tank.upgrade()

    println(tank.damage)
    // 12.5

    Tank.upgrade()

    println(tank.damage)
    // 15.0
    */
}
```

By the way, if you are using Swift 2, `println` has been renamed to `print`.